# Fade out one section and fade in the next section as you scroll on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site and I want each section to take up the screen and as you scroll down the page the sections fade out as the next section comes into view. I'm struggling on how this math needs to work.

For one section it's easy which is basically the height of the element and it's distance from the top to get the opacity percentage. However, I just can't quite figure out the math for other sections. I need section 2 to start fading in as section 1 is fading out.

I do not want to scrolljack. I just want a scrolling effect. Rather than override default scrolling behavior I just want to animate in/out as you scroll where a certain Y scroll value = a certain CSS value rather than a sort of "breakpoint" where it animates to a new "slide".

For the proper effect, for example, my math divides the height of the row by 2 so that it's 50% faded out as the next section should be fading in 50%. But, as of now, the math just doesn't work for the other sections.

This site is using vanilla JS as it's supposed to be a simple one pager.

Example below:

```js
    (function () {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');

          rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
            const distanceToTop = window.pageYOffset;
            const elementHeight = row.offsetHeight * (index + 1) / 2;
            row.style.opacity = ((elementHeight - distanceToTop) / elementHeight * 100) / 100;
          });
        });
      })();
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Manrope', helvetiva, sans-serif;
      transition: background-color 1s;
      color:#fff;
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, #100521 0%, #50357c 50%, #878290 100%);
    }

    header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    header h1 {
      font-family: 'Lack';
      font-size: 4em;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #100521;
    }

    .row-container .row:first-child {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .row {
      opacity: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;
    }

    .row-inner {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      flex: 50%;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .left-column {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .right-column {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: 'Unbounded', helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 36px;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    p {
      margin: 10px 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&family=Unbounded&family=Lack&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>My App</h1>
    </header>
    <!-- First row -->
    <div class="row-container">
      <div class="row section-1">
        <div class="row-inner">
          <div class="column left-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <h1>Headline 1</h1>
              <h2>Subhead 1</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column right-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Second row -->
      <div class="row section-2">
        <div class="row-inner">
          <div class="column left-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <h1>Headline 2</h1>
              <h2>Subhead 2</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column right-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Third row -->
      <div class="row section-3">
        <div class="row-inner">
          <div class="column left-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <h1>Headline 3</h1>
              <h2>Subhead 3</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column right-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Fourth row -->
      <div class="row section-4">
        <div class="row-inner">
          <div class="column left-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <h1>Headline 4</h1>
              <h2>Subhead 4</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column right-column">
            <div class="column-inner">
              <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971847/499581)?

Comment: You want to use `IntersectionObserver`, not `scroll` event listener.

Comment: @I'L'I that is just a faded out styling at the top and bottom of the container. I'm looking for the effect that if you had say <DIV 1> and <DIV 2> where DIV 1 is 100% opacity and DIv 2 is 0%. As you scroll down, based on the viewport, DIV 1 slowly goes to 0% and DIV 2 goes to 100%. Almost like a "crossfade" or "dissolve" except the layer arent on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really ask for a web component, I just got carried away. This is a fun challenge! Anyway, here's a version that is NOT a web component. I also realized that I missed all the css that you provided. So I added that as well. I'm not sure if tweaking the css a little is verbotten ... but I did it. I also added a single [section] tag, which wraps everything but the app header, to make it more bullet proof ... Please let me know if I need to use your code exactly as you posted it.

I had a lot of trouble finding settings that provide a dramatic enough effect on both large screens and phones without some ugly hacks, so I opted for a compromise. You can optimize for either large or small by changing the rootMargin option for the IntersectionObserver. Smaller values make the fade effect more dramatic, but values that are too small cause the content to look washed out on smaller devices. As I'm posting this, rootMargin is set to "-25px". Apparantly you can use negative values, but as far as I can tell, you can only use "px" as the measurement. Other measurements don't seem to work.

Sooooo...

I used IntersectionObserver

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(fadeInOut, options);
```

One of the options IntersectionObserver takes is something called "threshold". I don't totally understand it, but MDN suggested that if you want to poll the viewport to determine element visibility, you should set the value of "threshold" as an array with many numbers ranging from 0 to 1. The example provided a function that generates 20 of them, so that's what I used.

```
function buildThresholds() {
  const steps = 20;
  const thresholds = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
      let ratio = i/steps;
      thresholds.push(ratio);
   }

    thresholds.push(0);
    return thresholds;
  }
```

Then I grabbed the collection of elements to watch using querySelectorAll(".row-container").

Then I looped through the elements and added each one to the observer's watch list.

```
observer.observe(elem);
```

Then, in the callback you provide when you create a new instance of IntersectionObserver, I set each element's opacity to the the intersectionRatio, which is a property provided by the instance of the IntersectionObserverEntry which is passed to the callback.

```
function fadeInOut(items, observer) {
  items.forEach( (item) => {
      item.target.style.opacity = item.intersectionRatio;
  });
}
```

```js
function buildThresholds() {
  const steps = 20;
  const thresholds = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
      let ratio = i/steps;
      thresholds.push(ratio);
  }

  thresholds.push(0);
  return thresholds;
}

function fadeInOut(items, observer) {
  items.forEach( (item) => {
      item.target.style.opacity = item.intersectionRatio;
  });
}

function scrollFade() {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.row-container');
  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "-25px",
    threshold: buildThresholds()
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(fadeInOut, options);

  for (let elem of elems) {
    observer.observe(elem);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', scrollFade);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Manrope', helvetiva, sans-serif;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  color:#fff;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #100521 0%, #50357c 50%, #878290 100%);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Lack';
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #100521;
}

section {
  margin-top: 6em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Unbounded', helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row-container {
  background-color: rgb(16, 5, 33);
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.row-inner {
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 1 1 70vw;
}

.right-column {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>My App</h1>
</header>

<section>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline One</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead One</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline Two</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead Two</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-2.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline Three</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead Three</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-3.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline Four</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead Four</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-4.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline Five</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead Five</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-5.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <h1>Headline Six</h1>
                    <h2>Subhead Six</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-6.jpg" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but I think it's missing a key point of the CSS which is the position:sticky. That makes it stay in the center as you scroll and fade out. If you check out this site you can kind of see what i mean by using sticky to give the effect its animating elements as you scroll: https://samsung.com/sec/smartphones/galaxy-s22-ultra

Comment: Actually I figured it out! I selected a child element within it. While the overall "slide" or "row" doesnt move the elements inside move up / down. This works!

Comment: @Oscar Godson I'm sorry I misunderstood your requirements, but I'm happy it will work! The page you linked to is very nice. It's not just a brochure, it's a journey. I have bookmarked it. Really an inspirational piece of work.

Answer (score 3):

Let me know if you have any questions for modifying my code. (I've also had to change your css a bit - the content of the row element was higher than the row element itself what led to some weird issues.)

I have rewritten most of it and it should now work for large row heights. The math for it is just a quadratic formula (Opacity of offset from center of the screen) with it's roots at the height of the row and a maximum at 0 offset with a value of 1.

```js
/** @format */

const calculateOpacity = () => {
   const ROW_CONTAINER = document.querySelector(".row-container");
   const rows = ROW_CONTAINER.children;
   const rowContainerBBox = ROW_CONTAINER.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("calc")
   for (const row of rows) {
      const rowBBox = row.getBoundingClientRect();
      const top = rowBBox.top - rowContainerBBox.top;
      const bottom = rowBBox.bottom - rowContainerBBox.bottom;
      if (rowBBox.height > rowContainerBBox.height) {
         const opacityOfOffset = (offset) => {
            const a = -1 / Math.pow(rowBBox.height, 2);
            return Math.max(0, a * Math.pow(offset, 2) + 1);
         };
         row.style.opacity = opacityOfOffset(top + bottom);
         continue;
      }
      const unvisibleHeightTop = -Math.min(0, top);
      const unvisibleHeightBottom = Math.max(0, bottom);
      const visibleHeight = rowBBox.height - unvisibleHeightTop - unvisibleHeightBottom;
      row.style.opacity = visibleHeight / rowBBox.height;
   }
};
document.querySelector(".row-container").addEventListener("scroll", calculateOpacity);
```

```css
/** @format */
body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-family: "Manrope", helvetiva, sans-serif;
   color: #fff;
}
header {
   height: max(70px, 10vh);
   position: fixed;
   background-color: black;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
header h1 {
   margin: 0;
}

main {
   padding-top: max(70px, 10vh);
   height: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row-container {
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, #100521 0%, #50357c 50%, #878290 100%);
   height: calc(100vh - max(70px, 10vh));
   overflow-y: auto;
}

.row {
   height: 150vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 10vh 0;
}

.row .row-inner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.row .row-inner .col {
   margin-inline: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100%;
}

.row img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.row h2 {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Unbounded", helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 36px;
}
.row h3 {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 24px;
}

.row p {
   margin: 10px 0;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- @format -->

<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&family=Unbounded&family=Lack&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1>My App</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
         <div class="row-container">
            <div class="row row-1">
               <div class="row-inner">
                  <div class="col left">
                     <div class="col-inner">
                        <h2>Headline 1</h2>
                        <h3>Subhead 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col right">
                     <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-1">
               <div class="row-inner">
                  <div class="col left">
                     <div class="col-inner">
                        <h2>Headline 1</h2>
                        <h3>Subhead 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col right">
                     <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row row-1">
               <div class="row-inner">
                  <div class="col left">
                     <div class="col-inner">
                        <h2>Headline 1</h2>
                        <h3>Subhead 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col right">
                     <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! This is really close. A couple things is that the sticky factor isnt working. I spent some time playing with it but cant quite figure out why the sticky is no longer working. I know the parent has flex but i removed that too and still no luck. also the height of the panels will be large to give an illusion of as you scroll the background is changing colors. Making the height large seems to break the calculation. For an example you could set the height to like 300vh or something.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in one of the comments to your question, it's more effective to use IntersectionObserver rather than the 'scroll' event listener.

If I'm correct, this snippet should help you achieve what you're looking for:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  let options = {
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.8
  };

  const intersectionHandler = function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio > 0.8) {
        entry.target.classList.remove("fadeOut");
        entry.target.classList.add("fadeIn");
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove("fadeIn");
        entry.target.classList.add("fadeOut");
      }
    });
  };

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionHandler, options);
  document.querySelectorAll(".section").forEach((row, index) => {
    observer.observe(row);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: "Manrope", helvetiva, sans-serif;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #100521 0%, #50357c 50%, #878290 100%);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: "Lack";
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #100521;
}

.row-container .row:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-column {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.right-column {
  background-color: transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Unbounded", helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- First row -->
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="column left-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <h1>Headline 1</h1>
          <h2>Subhead 1</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second row -->
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="column left-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <h1>Headline 2</h1>
          <h2>Subhead 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Third row -->
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="column left-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <h1>Headline 3</h1>
          <h2>Subhead 3</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Fourth row -->
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="column left-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <h1>Headline 4</h1>
          <h2>Subhead 4</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum dolar Gamet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column right-column">
        <div class="column-inner">
          <img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice I've made some minor modifications to your HTML and CSS, but the magic happens in the Javascript.

I've also used the window "load" event listener to create the observer options, object and callback function when the page is loaded.

You can check the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) docs for more details on how it works and how to tweak the options or the callback to suit your needs.

Comment: I think the main difference here than what I was attempting to describe is this is triggered based. This mean scrolling down a bit and stopping will make it vanish completely rather than just faded out a little bit based on your scroll position. The UX issue is if you're scrolling quickly and something catches your eye and stop itll go away. Samsung has an extreme example but conceptually what I was looking for. As you scroll things move but they will never vanish as you're trying to read and scroll. samsung.com/sec/smartphones/galaxy-s22-ultra

Answer (score 1):

Will this work? I used IntersectionObserver and set the opacity of the sections based on the intersection ratio of each section with the viewport. I pretty much took the idea straight from MDN.
[MDN Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```js
class ScrollFade extends HTMLElement {

template;
shadow;
static observer = false;

constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    if (!ScrollFade.observer) {
        const buildThresholds = function() {
            const steps = 20;
            const thresholds = [];

            for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
                let ratio = i/steps;
                thresholds.push(ratio);
            }

            thresholds.push(0);
            return thresholds;
        }

        const options = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: buildThresholds()
        };

        ScrollFade.observer = new IntersectionObserver(ScrollFade.fadeInOut, options);
    }
}

connectedCallback() {
    const tmpl = document.querySelector('#scroll-fade-template').cloneNode(true);
    const template = tmpl.content;
    ScrollFade.observer.observe(this.shadow.host);
    this.shadow.append(template);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    ScrollFade.observer.unobserve(this.shadow.host);
}

static fadeInOut(items, observer) {
    items.forEach( (item) => {
        item.target.style.opacity = item.intersectionRatio;
    });
}
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', customElements.define('scroll-fade', ScrollFade));
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<scroll-fade>
  <h1 slot="headline">Headline One</h1>
  <h2 slot="subhead">Subhead One</h2>
  <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p>
  </div>
</scroll-fade>

<scroll-fade>
  <h1 slot="headline">Headline Two</h1>
  <h2 slot="subhead">Subhead Two</h2>
  <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p>
  </div>
</scroll-fade>

<scroll-fade>
  <h1 slot="headline">Headline Three</h1>
  <h2 slot="subhead">Subhead Three</h2>
  <img slot="avatar" src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/adventurer/team-member-3.jpg" alt="Image 1"> 
  <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p>
  </div>
</scroll-fade>


<template id="scroll-fade-template">
  <style>
    .row-container {
      background-color: seagreen;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .row-inner {
      align-content: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
      padding: 10px;
      gap: 10px;
    }

  .left-column {
    flex: 1 1 70vw;
  }

   .right-column {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row section">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <slot name="headline">Need Headline</slot>
                    <slot name="subhead">Need Subhead</slot>
                    <slot>Need Content</slot>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column">
                <div class="column-inner">
                    <slot name="avatar">Need Avatar</slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```