# Can we make a better div fade edges while scroll with only css?

Tags: html, css

I came up with this code after many tries to figure out how to make text fade on edges while scrolling with only CSS no JS/JQ:

```css
    
            :root {
                --custom-Width: 90%;
                --custom-hight: 24rem;
            }        
    
            body {
                display: flex;    
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
    
            .fadeEdgesDiv {
                margin-top: var(--custom-hight);
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 10rem;
                overflow-y: auto;       
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #000;
                width: var(--custom-Width);
                background-color: bisque;
            }
    
            .topEdge, .btmEdge   {
                position: absolute;            
                height: 2rem;
                width: calc(var(--custom-Width) - 30px );     
                margin-right: -220px;    
            }
    
            .topEdge {
                background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);    
            }
    
            .btmEdge  {         
                background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
                top: calc(var(--custom-hight) + 8.5rem );
            }
```

```html
        <div class="fadeEdgesDiv">
            <div class="topEdge"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>                                            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>                                            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>                                            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>                                            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>                                         
            <div class="btmEdge"></div>
        </div>
```

Could someone tell me if there is any other way to make it better or is there any alternatives? I found this [Question][1] but it uses JS also it fades the scroll bars as well which is not good behavior!

My code is running well however the problem in my code is whenever you try to change the position of the main DIV you have to change many parameters which is sort of headache for maintaining. So, any better way please?

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970529/css-div-fade-scroll-styling#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=You%20can%20use%20CSS%20mask,%2Fbottom%20of%20the%20element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970529/css-div-fade-scroll-styling#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=You%20can%20use%20CSS%20mask,%2Fbottom%20of%20the%20element)).

Comment: You can do it all with a single HTML element with a single CSS mask-image generated from a `linear-gradient`.

Comment: @Dai as mentioned above the example on the link showing how to use CSS mask-image like this `-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, black 48px, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%);`  simple and easy which will hide part of the scroll bars! :)